# How to use vkapi library PHP

Tags: php, api, class, vk

Already installed library using composer
*Я уже установил библиотеку через composer*

```
composer require vkcom/vk-php-sdk
```

But cant initializate it by
*однако не выходит её инициализировать через*

```
$vk = new VKApiClient();
```

Recieve error
*Получаю ошибку*

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VKApiClient' not found in E:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\albom.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\albom.php on line 2
>   [Directory hierarchy image
>
>   *Изображение иерархии директорий*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7XWn.png)

I already tried method below:
*Также я пробовал способ ниже:*

```
$vk = new \vkapi\src\VK\Client\VKApiClient();
```

But receive error:
*Но получаю ошибку:*

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'vkapi\src\VK\Client\VKApiClient' not found in E:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\albom.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\albom.php on line 2

Tried use require for composer autoload file, but it still doesnt works well
*Уже пробовал использовать require для автозагрузочного файла composer'a, но это всё равно не работает*

```
require '.\vendor\autoload.php';
$vk = new VKApiClient();
```

Recieve error
*Получаю ошибку*

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VKApiClient' not found in E:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\albom.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\albom.php on line 3

Comment: Load the autoloader.

Comment: Yes because it ignores class files check here https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk/blob/master/.gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different points here.

First, `VKApiClient`'s namespace is not `\vkapi\src\VK\Client\`. You can open a [file and read the code](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk/blob/master/src/VK/Client/VKApiClient.php). It doesn't contain `src` at all, it does contain `namespace VK\Client`, so you can initialize client this way

```
$vk = new \VK\Client\VKApiClient();
```

Second, you have to include source file. Composer does it via `autoload.php`. If is not actual somehow, try `php composer dump-autoload` to refresh autoload file.

Actually, you'd better use English only. Russian SO is [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Have you tried to ask your question there? Though audience is much greater here, I prefer English SO rather that Russian.